# How can I remove moles permanently?

Tags: personal-care

I have a lot of moles on my body, specially on my face and neck. How can I get rid of these moles permanently without getting marks? Is there a way to get rid of them, preferably without pain?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is about a health issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take half spoon of baking soda in half spoon of coconut oil ,mix well then  apply it on your unwanted moles before going to bed.apply daily it until you got the results.